# iPad to control Mac Pro computer audio system

Tags: apple-music, music.app, apple-remote-desktop

**Technology**

Mine

- MacPro macOS
- 11.0.1 Big Sur

My wife's

- iPad Pro
- iPadOS 14.2

**Stereo system**

MacPro has a hardwired digital connection to my stereo system's DAC.
No other available inputs (wireless or bluetooth) into the stereo system.

So, I can not send music directly from any other device to the stereo system.  The stereo has no other inputs remote or otherwise.

I use Apple's Music app.
Works perfectly.

**Goal**

Enable my wife's iPadPro to remotely access my Mac Pro's Music app.
So she can play music on the attached stereo system.

Note: She has a different AppleID than I do, but I could let her use mine if it would help.

Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of half an answer as it's been so long since I actually did this that the method is a bit hazy…
Apple's iTunes Remote - https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/itunes-remote/id284417350 There's a one-off sign in procedure to authorise 'foreign' remotes.

Comment: It works perfectly for me, although I am on the same Apple-ID.

Comment: There's some kind of 'who can join' pref, but it's been so long since I used it I really cannot remember. I used it at parties (remember when we used to have those?;) & could allow anyone or just certain users to join & add to playlist/next up etc.

Comment: I use the Apple Remote from my own iPad and it works fine.  I do have to have "Sound - Output" manually set on my Mac Pro to "Digital".  True remote access to my Mac Pro desktop over the wireless network might work for that.  The newest version of the Remote app even gives me access to Apple Music's streaming content, which shows up in my music Library.  The problem... I have not found a way to assign, "who can join" so that another user's device (and associated Apple IDs) can access my Mac Pro and thereby my otherwise thoroughly modern computer audio system ;-(